# Расширение Google Chrome для изменения стартовой страницы

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, chrome-extension

Хотел бы узнать, как сделать расширение которое после установки видоизменяло бы стартовую страницу браузера Google Chrome.
Например [этого](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/momentum/laookkfknpbbblfpciffpaejjkokdgca?hl=ru)

Answer (score 3):

в manifest.json в поле

```json
"content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": [
        "<all_urls>"
      ],
      "js": [
        "js/content.js"
      ]
    }
  ]
```

Указываешь путь к фалу js.
Дальше пишешь в content.js любой код. как будто это твоя страница

Для изменения стартовой страницы браузера можно использовать

```
"chrome_url_overrides" : {
    "newtab": "index2.html"
  },
```

Comment: А html код где будет?

Comment: ты можешь через js создавать html разметку. 
и выводить ее.
Реагировать на все изменения в твоей модалке, или перекидывать на другую страницу. + можешь в поле 
```"browser_action": {
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  }
```
Указать модальное окно которое будет появляться при клике на значок расширения

Comment: Через js писать html разметку как-то не очень удобно... А нельзя ли как-то через html файл?

Comment: @iKey на счет этого не знаю. мне кажется что нет. 
но ничего тебе не мешает сделать свою страницу на гитхабе например. сделать git pages и переадресовывать пользователя на нее через js
А еще можно сделать страницу в html файле. Потом через ```innerHTML``` вставить его в ноду. Ну и вывести на страницу или ```append()``` и подобные.

Comment: Нет, пользователя никуда перевдресовывать нельзя. momentum же как-то сделали

Comment: @iKey поставил плагин. понял что вы хотели. Отредактировал ответ